# What does mean that P(λ) is the prior probability in a Hidden Markov Model?

Tags: hidden-markov-models, markov

Given the following parameters:

- λ = (A,B,π).
- A = the state transition matrix
- A = { a[i][j] } = { P(state q[i] at t | state q[j] at t+1) },
- B = the observation matrix and
- π = the initial distribution.

It is correct the sentence below? (making explicit the relation between λ and A):

a[i][j] = P(state q[i] at t | state q[j] at t+1) =P(state q[i] at t | state q[j] at t+1, λ)

Please some help!

Comment: An addition, even though it's old: Already the assumption is a bit odd. Normally you will have `a[i][j] = P(state j at time t | state i at time t-1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
P(state q[i] at t | state q[j] at t+1) =P(state q[i] at t | state q[j] at t+1, λ)
```

This expression would be

```
P(state q[i] at t | state q[j] at t+1) =P(state q[i] at t | state q[j] at t+1, λ) / P(λ)
```

Comment: Thanks Nicko for your response. To better understand your answer, let me ask the following: The event (state q[j] at t+1) is independent of (λ)? and the event ((state q[i] at t) ∩ (state q[j] at t+1)) is independant of (λ) ?    Thanks again.